# Does openfire support User / contact blocking?

Tags: xmpp, openfire

Does openfire support User / contact blocking??

I am creating a XMPP based chat. Now i want my users to have a facility by which they can actively block a certain person from chatting with them.

I know XMPP have defined an extension for
communications blocking (defined in Privacy Lists[XEP-0016]), as well as a stripped-down interface to privacy lists (defined in  Simple Communications Blocking
[XEP-0191]).

But when implementing these extension a server request of blocking the user gives me a response

My questions is does openfire(I am using Openfire 3.7.1) supports these extensions if yes where should I go and enable the plugging if not what is the alternate available

Comment: Hi Vivek, were you able to find an answer to this question?

Answer (score 1):

Openfire supports the privacy list XEP (and has been since a long time, including the 3.7.1.release that you're referring to). The Spark client (another project on IgniteRealtime.org) can make use of this. This client also sports a debug window, in which you can see what related XMPP stanzas are exchanged to set up the list.