# Deny messages from non-roster users in Openfire

Tags: xmpp, openfire, converse.js

How do I only allow contacts who are on my roster list to send me messages?
Is there any XEP responsible to do that? Or will I need to do this client-side?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that by default converse.js doesn't show messages received from users who are not in your roster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, OpenFire supports [XEP-0016: Privacy Lists](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0016.html) (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142048/does-openfire-support-user-contact-blocking)), which can be used to block stanzas according to various criteria.

You can't explicitly block stanzas for contacts not in your roster, but you can block by subscription status `none`, which can more or less accomplish the same goal.  You could send something like this:

```xml
<iq from='romeo@example.net/orchard' type='set' id='msg3'>
<query xmlns='jabber:iq:privacy'>
  <list name='message-sub-example'>
    <item type='subscription'
          value='none'
          action='deny'
          order='5'>
      <message/>
    </item>
  </list>
</query>
</iq>
```

This creates a privacy list called `message-sub-example`, containing a rule to block any messages from contacts with subscription type `none`, including contacts not in the roster.  For this list to take effect, you need to make it the active list:

```xml
<iq from='romeo@example.net/orchard' type='set' id='active1'>
<query xmlns='jabber:iq:privacy'>
  <active name='message-sub-example'/>
</query>
</iq>
```

Comment: Yes, it might be worth learning about the four subscription states: `none`, `to`, `from` and `both`. Unlike other IM systems, presence subscriptions are not necessarily symmetric: if X can see Y, Y may or may not be able to see X.