# how to block communication between two users in openfire

Tags: openfire

Using privacy list manager to handle blocked users i can be able to store and retrieve blocked users. but not be able to block the communication between the blocked users. will openfire support XEP-0016 fully? if it supports then why am getting message from blocked users, Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Privacy Lists are supported in Openfire but there is no specific mention of XEP-0016.

Privacy lists are stored in "ofPrivacyList" table in database. If you are blocking a user, then verify from this table that if it's entry exists there or not.

Same is answered here: [Does openfire support User / contact blocking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142048/does-openfire-support-user-contact-blocking)

Comment: privacyList are saving my database but, openfire is not blocking communication. can you tell me if any configuration for this to work in openfire?

Comment: are you trying it from your code or using some existing XMPP clients? like Spark?

Comment: Using openfire server and client library smack

Comment: Can you try the same from desktop client Spark? Simply login your 2 users in it and try to block communication. The feature is available in Openfire, so it should work from Spark. and If it's working then you need to check at Smack side that what you are missing there.